# カテゴリ別に分けられたボタンを押す→カテゴリ毎の一覧をテーブルビューに表示 （押されたボタンに対応するカテゴリのセクションに遷移）

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, json

はじめての質問になります。

ある地域のお店紹介アプリを開発中です。  トップページにボタンが９つ、各カテゴリ毎に分けられ並んでいます。

[image: お店カテゴリ→カテゴリ別お店一覧]

例えば 「Restaurant」 というカテゴリのボタンを押すと、 「Restaurant」 のカテゴリ（セクション）に括られたお店一覧がテーブルビューに表示される、といった仕様を考えています。

テーブルビューに表示させるデータはいまのところローカルに JSON で用意してあり、単純にデータ一覧をテーブルビューに表示させるのはうまくいきました。できればこの JSON ファイルをそのまま利用して上記機能を実装できないものかと考えていますが、できるものなのでしょうか。

また可能な場合、どういったコーディングが考えられるか、どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

※追記 JSONファイル例

JSON、配列の仕組みがよくわかっておらず、説明がうまくできないのですが、例をあげると、以下のようになります。

"aaa":  [

{"name": "飲食店a", "category":"restaurant", "url":"http://-----", "address":"東京都------", "lat":"34.000000", "lon":"135.000000", "tel":"000-000-000", "img":"a.png"},

{"name": "飲食店b", "category":"restaurant", "url":"http://-----","address":"東京都------", "lat":"31.000000", "lon":"131.000000", "tel":"000-000-000", "img":"a.png"},

{"name": "服屋a", "category":"fashion", "url":"http://-----", "address":"東京都------", "lat":"32.000000", "lon":"133.000000","tel":"000-000-000", "img":"b.png"},

{"name": "服屋b", "category":"fashion", "url":"http://-----","address":"東京都------", "lat":"33.000000", "lon":"134.000000", "tel":"000-000-000", "img":"b.png"}

]

こういった感じで100件ほどのデータが並んでおり、機能としては「Restaurant」のボタンを押したらテーブルビューにカテゴリ"restraunt"の一覧（飲食店a,b......）が表示、「Fashion」のボタンを押したらカテゴリ"fashion"の一覧（服屋a,b......）が表示、というふうにできればと考えています。

Comment: NSJSONSerializationというクラスがあるのはごぞんじですか？あなたがご存じか否かで、回答内容が変わってくるでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。説明不足で申し訳ありません。NSJSONSerializationクラスは存じております。JSONを読み込んでArray等に格納、それらをテーブルに表示させるというような動きはそれなりに理解しているつもりなのですが、ボタンを押す→押されたボタンに対応するデータを表示する、という動きを実装するのに悩んでいます。イメージとしては、カテゴリ別のボタンを押す→そのカテゴリのキーが振られたJSONデータ一覧がテーブルビューに表示される、といったことなのですが、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: JSONの例を載せる事と「できればこの JSON ファイルをそのまま利用して」の辺りを正確に(詳細に)表現することで質問と回答の質が上がると思います。私の場合「JSONファイルをそのまま=JSONをパースしない」と理解しましたが、それが正しいという自信が持てないため回答ができません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。たしかにわかりづらい質問で申し訳ありません。JSONファイルをそのまま、というのは、人から預かったJSONファイルをそのまま利用してということでした。ローカル（メインバンドル）に保持していてもテーブルビューに表示するにはパースが必要だと認識しております。あらためてJSONの例を質問に載せるようにします。

Answer (score 4):

上記のコメントを考慮した上で、
流れとしては以下のようになります。
1. JSONデータをNSArrayにNSDictionary形式で入れる（以下例ではNSMutableArrayにNSDictionaryを入れています）

```
NSMutableArray *allArr = [NSMutableArray array];

arr = [@[@{@"name": @"飲食店a", @"category": @"restaurant"},
@{@"name": @"飲食店b", @"category": @"restaurant"},
@{@"name": @"飲食店c", @"category": @"restaurant"},
@{@"name": @"スポーツセンターa", @"category": @"sports"},
@{@"name": @"スポーツセンターb", @"category": @"sports"}] mutableCopy];
```

2. 高速列挙でrestaurantのみを取り出す

```
NSMutableArray *restaurantArr = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dic in allArr) {
  if ([dic[@"category"] isEqualToString:@"restaurant"]) {
    [restaurantArr addObject:dic];
  }
}
```

これでrestaurantArr には、カテゴリー：レストランのDictionaryが入ることになります。